# Is this a real Duplo Train Base or fake?

Tags: trains, duplo

I'm new to LEGO, so forgive me if this is a simple question. I purchased a [lot of 30 Duplo Train Base](http://web.archive.org/web/20150305053938/http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-30-Train-Cars-Lego-Base-Duplo-Blocks-Blue-Red-Yellow-/231492998201) from eBay.

Below is the picture that accompanied the listing. There is a disclaimer stating: `(Stock Pictures colors of trains may be different)`

[image]

What I received aside from the 20 that fit the Duplo Train Base plus 10 of these train bases:

[image]

The LEGO DUPLO Creative Suitcase 10565 shows the train base with a pincher tip and not a closed loop:

[image]

Not sure, what the other 10 train bases I received are. The 10 cars do seem to say DUPLO inside the circle if I look closely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These 10 are [Duplo Vehicle Car Base 2 x 6 with Hitches and Red Wheels (Old)' (4883cx2)](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4883cx2) and came in Red, Blue and Yellow

[image]

Comment: +1 for Lego floor :) Yes, it sounds like they are the vehicle car base and not train base?

Comment: As far as I can see they are same parts, where 10 are old version (till 1992) and the other 20 [Duplo Chassis 2X6](http://brickset.com/parts/6045958) the updated version (from 1993 - now)

Comment: There is a simmilar looking part that can run on corresponding duplo tracks [Duplo Train Base 2 x 6 with Red Wheels and Swiveling Coupling' (4559cx1)](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4559cx1). I don't know if Lego released different types of track over the years, and if they are all compatable with each other.

Comment: The car base w/ hitch fits, but it more loose than the train base.

Answer (score 6):

A legitimate duplo train part will have the word Duplo imprinted inside each round stud, like you see in the image here, sorry for the fuzzy pic.

[image: this image here]

-Brian from [brickablocks](http://brickablocks.com).

Comment: ... or sometimes LEGO. http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/what-logos-appear-on-duplo-brick-studs